# Python Socket Connection Hangs On Different Instance but Works on Same Instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sockets

I'm currently using two different AWS instances to try and communicate using two python files, one a client and one a server. One instance, Server, has a copy of the server file and the client file. The other instance, Client, has only a copy of the client file.

The problem is that when I run the client file on the Server instance, it works as intended. However, when I run the client file on the Client instance, it hangs on the socket.connect call.

server.py

```
import socket
# create a socket object
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# get local machine name. I have also used ''
host = socket.gethostname()
# I use this print to set the host name in the client file.
print(host)

port = 12000 

# bind to the port
serversocket.bind((host, port))

# queue up to 5 requests
serversocket.listen(5)

while True:
    # establish a connection
    clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()
    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))

    msg='Thank you for connecting'+ "\r\n"
    clientsocket.send(msg.encode('ascii'))
    clientsocket.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket
# create a socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# host is hard-coded to the output of the server file's gethostname() result
# hard-coded value from server.py
host = '###.##.##.##'
port = 12000

# connect. This is where the code hangs when run in the terminal
s.connect((host, port))

# Receive no more than 1024 bytes
msg = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print (msg.decode('ascii'))
```

I've checked my security group on my AWS instances as well. Both of them have the same security group, which includes:

```
Custom ICMP Rule - IPv4 Echo Reply N/A 0.0.0.0/0 ICMP
Custom ICMP Rule - IPv4 Echo Reply N/A ::/0 ICMP
```

which I believe should allow things to run properly.

I'm unsure as to where I could be going wrong. I am certain that both client files are the same and that both servers have the same security group. I read that socket.gethostname() should return a value that is accessible from the public, so I don't think my host address is wrong. The port number is also correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ICMP rules do not enable TCP/IP connections. You need a rule for TCP and your port number.

Comment: Oh whoops, makes sense. Seems my professor mentioned the wrong rule. Works as intended now, thanks @JohnHanley

Comment: The ICMP protocol allows the `ping` command to function.

Answer (score 0):

My issue what that I was missing a TCP rule with source allowing "Anywhere". I was under the impression that ICMP was the only rule I needed given my assignment, but that seems to not be the case. Thanks for the help.